# Graphql resolve mapping with makeExecutableSchema

Tags: graphql, graphql-js, apollostack, apollo-server

I am having problems trying to resolve fields inside a GraphQL type.
So, here I am trying to resolve the `find` property of `patientQuery`

```
const gqlSchema = makeExecutableSchema({
    typeDefs: `
  type patientQuery {
    find: [String]
    findOne: String
  }
  type Query {
    patient: patientQuery
  }
  type Mutation {
    addPost(name: String, title: String, content: String): patientQuery
  }
  schema {
    query: Query
    mutation: Mutation
  }
  `,
    resolvers: {
      patientQuery: {
        find(root, params, context, ast) {
          console.log('testing');
          return ['title'];
        }
      }
    }
  });
```

but when I do a query like this

```
{
  patient {
    find
  }
}
```

I always get null

```
{
  "data": {
    "patient": null
  }
}
```

So what is the proper way to resolve the fields inside the `patientQuery` type?

Comment: At first look, I suspect it has to do with the fact that you're returning a string but the field is expected to return an array of string.

Try returning `return ['title']`

Comment: changed the resolve function returning an array but still I get null

Answer (score 1):

So, I've found out the problem. 
The `Query` type had to resolve the patient field so that it won't return `null`.

So the new resolvers object will look like this, in order to solve the issue

```
 resolvers: {
  Query: {
    patient() {
      return true;
    }
  },
  patientQuery: {
    find(root, params, context, ast) {
      console.log('testing');
      return [ 'title' ];
    }
  }
}
```

the old one :-

```
resolvers: {
  patientQuery: {
    find(root, params, context, ast) {
      console.log('testing');
      return ['title'];
    }
  }
}
```